# Spring Security on a non Spring Web app

Tags: spring, spring-security

Am trying to use Spring Security but all the tutorial I've found use the Spring framework for web application:

So my Question is:

Is it possible to use the Spring Security in a simple java web application without using the Spring Framework or are they linked together?

**UPDATE**

Well in fact, I've make a simple Java web Application using JPA - JSP on netbeans. So now I've decided to add some security. After some search, I found Shiro, Spring Security, And JAAS. So if I use maven, I could download the Spring Security dependencies without using the Spring famework, right?

**UPDATE 2**

Here is the XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
            version="3.0">
        <session-config>
            <session-timeout>
                30
            </session-timeout>
        </session-config>

            <listener>
                <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
            </listener>

            <context-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>
                    /WEB-INF/MyDispatcherServlet-servlet.xml
                </param-value>
            </context-param>

            <servlet>
                <servlet-name>MyDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            </servlet>

            <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>MyDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>*.go</url-pattern>
            </servlet-mapping>

            <filter>
                <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
                <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
            </filter>

            <filter-mapping>
                <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
                <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            </filter-mapping>

    </web-app>
```

This is the the server log error when I run the app:

```
        GRAVE: Class [ Lorg/apache/commons/logging/Log; ] not found. Error while loading [ class org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Jsr250MethodSecurityMetadataSource ]
        ATTENTION: Error in annotation processing: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/commons/logging/Log;
        GRAVE: Class [ Lorg/apache/commons/logging/Log; ] not found. Error while loading [ class org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Jsr250MethodSecurityMetadataSource ]
        ATTENTION: Error in annotation processing: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/commons/logging/Log;
        GRAVE: Class [ Lorg/apache/commons/logging/Log; ] not found. Error while loading [ class org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.SimpleHttpServerJaxWsServiceExporter ]
        ATTENTION: Error in annotation processing: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/commons/logging/Log;
        GRAVE: PWC1306: Startup of context /SpringTestApp_mvn5 failed due to previous errors
        GRAVE: PWC1305: Exception during cleanup after start failed
        org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: PWC2769: Manager has not yet been started
                at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stop(StandardManager.java:892)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:5456)
                at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.stop(WebModule.java:530)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5284)
                at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:499)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:912)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:694)
                at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1947)
                at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1619)
                at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:90)
                at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:126)
                at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:241)
                at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:236)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:339)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:183)
                at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:272)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:305)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:320)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1176)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$900(CommandRunnerImpl.java:83)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1224)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:365)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:204)
                at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:166)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:100)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:245)
                at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
                at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
                at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
                at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
                at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
                at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
                at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
                at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
                at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
                at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
                at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
                at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
                at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

        GRAVE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
        org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5289)
                at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:499)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:912)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:694)
                at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1947)
                at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1619)
                at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:90)
                at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:126)
                at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:241)
                at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:236)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:339)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:183)
                at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:272)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:305)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:320)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1176)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$900(CommandRunnerImpl.java:83)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1224)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:365)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:204)
                at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:166)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:100)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:245)
                at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
                at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
                at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
                at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
                at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
                at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
                at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
                at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
                at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
                at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
                at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
                at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
                at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
                at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:191)
                at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:4664)
                at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:535)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5266)
                ... 38 more
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
                at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
                at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:959)
                at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1430)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
                ... 43 more

        ATTENTION: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:932)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:912)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:694)
                at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1947)
                at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1619)
                at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:90)
                at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:126)
                at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:241)
                at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:236)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:339)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:183)
                at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:272)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:305)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:320)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1176)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$900(CommandRunnerImpl.java:83)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1224)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:365)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:204)
                at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:166)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:100)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:245)
                at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
                at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
                at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
                at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
                at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
                at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
                at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
                at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
                at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
                at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
                at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
                at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
                at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

        GRAVE: Exception while invoking class com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication start method
        java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
                at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:117)
                at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:126)
                at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:241)
                at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:236)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:339)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:183)
                at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:272)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:305)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:320)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1176)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$900(CommandRunnerImpl.java:83)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1224)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:365)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:204)
                at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:166)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:100)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:245)
                at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
                at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
                at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
                at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
                at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
                at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
                at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
                at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
                at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
                at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
                at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
                at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
                at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

        GRAVE: Exception while loading the app
        java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
                at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:117)
                at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:126)
                at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:241)
                at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:236)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:339)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:183)
                at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:272)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:305)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:320)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1176)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$900(CommandRunnerImpl.java:83)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1224)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:365)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:204)
                at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:166)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:100)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:245)
                at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
                at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
                at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
                at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
                at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
                at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
                at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
                at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
                at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
                at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
                at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
                at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
                at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inclusion of `spring` in your application includes the spring security implementations in it(which is a ultimately a java class implementation). I don't think there is a benefit in NOT including `spring` framework in your application, but to include ONLY its security implementations.

Comment: Well in fact, I've make a simple Java web Application using JPA - JSP on netbeans. So now I've decided to add some security. After some search, I found Shiro, Spring Security, And JAAS. So if I use maven, I could download the Spring Security dependencies without using the Spring famework, right?

Comment: Yes. But ultimately you need to include your configurations for including the spring security in the xml file to make it useful to your app. 
Maven can just provide you. I don't think you can use it without configuring it in xml. 

If you have brought in successfully, please post your answer :)

Comment: It's not right, using maven to download Spring Security, will automatically download Spring Security dependencies, including the Spring Framework, as documented in the manual, http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/appendix-dependencies.html, and in the maven pom files, http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/3.1.4.RELEASE/spring-security-core-3.1.4.RELEASE.pom.

Comment: @Asme: The error seems to be wrt logger. Please check if your jar files are included properly.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is not possible as Spring Security is built on top of Spring framework.

Though you can configure the maven to download Spring Security dependencies only , your project will not be executed succesfully and `NoClassDefFoundError` exception will thrown out at some points because the source codes of the Spring Security uses many classes and features from the Spring framework .

If you want to use the security framework that does not depend on spring framework , please check out [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/)

Comment: Hello, Ive try Apache Shiro (that I find easier by the way), but got some error when trying to add functionality, I'll open another post for it right now.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible, Spring Security needs the Spring Framework to instantiate the classes in order to provide its features.

You can review here the dependencies for Spring Security in [the manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/appendix-dependencies.html).

The Spring versions required by Spring Security is published on the [Spring Security web site](http://www.springsource.org/spring-security):

> - Spring Security 3.2.0.M1 is the latest development release (requires Java 1.5+ and Spring 3.2.0+)
> - Spring Security 3.1.4.RELEASE is the latest production release (requires Java 1.5+ and Spring 3.0.7+)
> - Spring Security 3.0.8.RELEASE is the previous production release (requires Java 1.5+ and Spring 3.0.6+)

In fact Spring Security POM modules show some of the dependencies:

- [the pom for spring-security-core](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/3.1.4.RELEASE/spring-security-core-3.1.4.RELEASE.pom)
- [the pom for spring-security-web](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/3.1.4.RELEASE/spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.pom)

Answer (score 1):

you can use maven-aspectj-plugin for this. When a class annotated with @Configurable annotation, this plugin can inject dependencies at compile time.@Configurable is a Spring annotation that allows dependencies to be injected into objects instantiated external to Spring. You dont have to make all your project based on spring

Answer (score 0):

When using Spring Security without Spring Boot, the preferred way is to leverage Spring Security’s BOM to ensure a consistent version of Spring Security is used throughout the entire project.
Reference [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#maven-without-spring-boot).
And you can initiliaze your app using [SecurityWebApplicationInitializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#abstractsecuritywebapplicationinitializer-without-existing-spring).